# Is forwarding to port 9 (discard) essentially the same as blocking a port?

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, port

My router (Linksys WRT1900ac) seems to leave port 4567 open, [as discussed in this question](https://superuser.com/questions/823514/if-my-dsl-modem-leaves-a-port-open-how-vulnerable-is-my-router). I'd like to block that port.

Unfortunately I see no easy way in the Linksys admin console to simply drop traffic from a specific port. However, it does allow port forwarding and triggering

I've learned that TCP port 9 is for the "[discard protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discard_Protocol)". If a host is listening on that port, it's supposed to discard the packets without comment.

If I forward traffic from port 4567 to port 9, am I in effect blocking the port? If something is listening on 9, the packets should be dropped without comment. And if nothing is listening on 9, I assume they'll just go into the bit-bucket on their own.

**Update**
Using Twisty's tip [in this post](https://superuser.com/questions/823514/if-my-dsl-modem-leaves-a-port-open-how-vulnerable-is-my-router), I've confirmed that my DSL modem, not my router, is leaving the port open. The modem doesn't seem to forward this traffic to the router, so no action I take on the router will affect the fact that the port is open.

Comment: At least my router, which does TR-069 on port 8089 would just ignore any rules affecting that port :/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty clever way of doing it, but anyway short answer, yes this would work as port 9 pretty much nullifies any data it receives.